# add_filter return value

Tags: filters

```
function validate_username( $username ) {
    $sanitized = sanitize_user( $username, true );
    $valid = ( $sanitized == $username );

    return apply_filters( 'validate_username', $valid, $username );
}
```

in wp-includes/registration.php i want to change

```
$sanitized = sanitize_user( $username, true );
```

to

```
$sanitized = sanitize_user( $username, false );
```

I couldnt success to write add_filter in there, somehow its not working. Can you write a filter for this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
function my_validate_username( $valid, $username ) {
    $sanitized = sanitize_user( $username, false );
    $valid = ( $sanitized == $username );

    return $valid;
}

add_filter('validate_username', 'my_validate_username', 10, 2);
```

Comment: i am adding this change to core for turkish chars:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15248 but when i use this add_filter i am getting error:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in wp-includes\formatting.php on line 2785

How can i fix this any idea?

Comment: Add some error checking in that case. The general idea is what is highlighted above: override the WP function entirely using the filter.

Answer (score -1):

So the problem is caused by this line in wp-includes/user.php:

$user_login = sanitize_user($user_login, true);

which causes sanitize_true to be strict, which reduced to ascii.

Change to false to work around, who knows what other bugs this will cause since apparently non-latin logins in wordpress is not supported, see this thread:

http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/accents-in-username#post-19037